# error: expected initializer before '->' token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
void creatore(int c, int first, int var)
{
    cell *n=new cell;
    cell *n->data=first;
```

and this is the error

basic list.cpp:26:12: error: expected initializer before '->' token

cell *n->data=53;

can someone help me out!

Comment: You are trying to redeclare `n`. Remove `cell*` from second line.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared your variable at

> cell *n=new cell;

at the next line you are trying to re-declare it

> cell *n->data=first;

Replace it with:

```
n->data=first;
```